# Start first call of IntervalObservable instant

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using an `IntervalObservable` to make continuous calls to the server side of my application. I can subscribe and unsubscribe to to the Oberservable and everything works fine with one exception:

The first call to the server is delayed, but I want it to be instant. The behaviour of the `IntervalObservable` is in principle correct, but does not match my requirements.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  private apiURL = 'assets/file.json'; 

  getList() {
       return IntervalObservable.create(1000).flatMap(() 
       => this.http.get(this.apiURL))
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    var fooot = new Foo();
    fooot.fillFromJSON(JSON.stringify(res.json()));
    return fooot;
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return IntervalObservable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

So how can I call the server instant on the first call and afterwards with the defined delay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things,

1. You can use the factory methods instead of the derived types, i.e. `Observable.interval(3000)` instead of `IntervalObservable.create`
2. You can use `timer` to do it with a single operator instead:

   ```
   return Observable.timer(0, 1000)
     .flatMapTo(this.http.get(this.apiURL))
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError);
   ```

Comment: Okay I finally chose this as an answer, because it is documented (in rxjs) (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md) and I like the factory method instead of an extra import.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [startWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html).

Following example pushes an event on the stream when it is created:

```
 getList() {
    return IntervalObservable.create(1000)
     .startWith(1) // needs a value, but won't be used
     .flatMap(() => this.http.get(this.apiURL))
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError);  
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat) and [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) for this:

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4kdJRD7HZqrbce7MFPW7

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

let httpRequest = () => Observable.of('response');

Observable.of(null)
  .concat(Observable.interval(3000))
  .concatMap(httpRequest)
  .subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
```

The first request is triggered with `Observable.of(null)` which goes through the operator chain and triggers `httpRequest`. Then it's all up to the `Observable.interval` operator.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works, too, but I chose the other one because it is more compact and clear (in my option). But Thanks, too!

Answer (score 2):

**For #RxJS Version 5+ :**

You can use [rxjs interval operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html) and implement polling. The following implemention will execute the `this.statusService.getStatus()` line in every 1000 ms interval :

```
 getList() {
     return Observable.interval(1000).startWith(1)
     .mergeMapTo(this.http.get(this.apiURL))
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

With `startWith(1)` added, now, it will be immediately executed without any delay and after that it will be executed every 1 sec interval. 
I think this is what you want.

**Or Another approach:** you can use [timer operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) and do the following:

```
getList() {
    return Observable.timer(0, 1000)
      .mergeMapTo(this.http.get(this.apiURL))
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In this approach, the timer operator will instantly execute and after that it will execute in every 1000 ms.

Also don't forget to import :

```
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMapTo';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
```