# How to drop the response of an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

With the help of [Observable.timer(0, 1000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994096/start-first-call-of-intervalobservable-instant) I am making continuous requests to my server in a defined time pattern. After I processed the content of the response it is possible under special conditions and **depending on the previous response** that I need to drop the response and therefore do not pass it to the subscriber of the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  private apiURL = 'assets/file.json'; 

  getList() {
    return Observable.timer(0, 1000)
      .concatMap(() => this.http.get(this.apiURL))
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError););
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    var fooot = new Foo();
    fooot.fillFromJSON(JSON.stringify(res.json()));
    if(fooot.getProperty()){
    //DROP IT
    }
    return fooot;
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

The `getList()` method is then called from `ngOnInit` of a component.
At the moment there are two possible solutions I can think of, buy maybe there is a better/clearer approach to solve this problem:

1. If I have to drop the response I create a special object which is recognized by the subscriber of `getList()` and then specifically handled. But this solution would be very ugly because the dropped response leaves my service and I need to extra write code outside of the service to handle this case.
2. I throw an exception when I have to drop the response. Then the exception is caught, recognized (to differ it from other cases) and then dropped without any notice/output. Afterwards the observable is restarted. The advantage of this approach is that the observable which should be dropped to not leave the service, but I do not like the usage of exceptions in this case for the control flow.

I tried both solutions and they are working, but I hope there are some better approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `distinctUntilChanged` to archive my goal:

```
getList() {
    return Observable.timer(0, 1000)
      .concatMap(() => this.http.get(this.apiURL)
      .distinctUntilChanged(null, x => x.json().info[1].value)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Therefore if the current and last response share the same specific value, the newest response is dropped. I guess my question was not clear enough and I did not mention that the decision to drop a response depends on the previous one.

A **downside** of this approach is that the response have to be parsed twice, but I guess that cannot be avoided. It would be nice to know if the json approch is faster than a complete string compare of the result (body).

If the decision to drop a response only depends on the current response, I would recommend to use a [filter](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html#collapseRxJS).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the `switchMap` operator.

If no response arrives within 1 second (the specified interval) the HTTP request is silently canceled, and another one is started.

Update:

If you are looking to cancel the HTTP request manually, you have to create a `cancelSubject: Subject` and define a `takeUntil(cancelSubject)` on the HTTP request.

To cancel the HTTP request, you simply call `cancelSubject.next(true)`, which in turn will cancel the HTTP request, because `takeUntil` takes effect.

Keep in mind, that after a second, the request will be restarted. If you want to cancel the timer, you will have to put the `.takeUntil(cancelSubject)` on the outer observable.

Comment: I do not want to stop a http request, I just want to ignore/drop the response of it.